# \seq_put_right does not execute when placed in an enumerate's item

Tags: lists, enumerate, expl3

```
\documentclass[a4paper, titlepage, twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\seq_new:N \myStack

\begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item\seq_put_right:Nn \myStack {1}
    \end{enumerate}

    \seq_put_right:Nn \myStack {1}  

    \seq_count:N \myStack
\end{document}
```

This code outputs:

```
  1.
1
```

which leads me to believe that the `\seq_put_right` command is not being executed when placed inside the `\item`. However, it works outside the enumerate.

How can I make this command execute and add the value to the sequence/stack?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It does execute, but makes local assignments that are discarded at `\end{enumerate}`, you see the same with a simple `{}` group, it is not connected to `\item`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, titlepage, twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\seq_new:N \myStack

\begin{document}
{\seq_put_right:Nn \myStack {1}}


    \seq_put_right:Nn \myStack {1}  

    \seq_count:N \myStack
\end{document}
```

You can use `\seq_gput_right:Nn` to make global assignments.

Comment: that often helps :-) though not always